# TypeError: Fullscreen request denied when tested application is automatically going into Full screen

Tags: cypress

It's my first post on the stackoverflow so I apologize in advance if I am doing something wrong.

I'm new to Cypress E2E test. Im trying to write a test for react WebApplication.
Unfortunately I am stuck on the element when the application on mobile views e.g. viewPort 360 opens in full screen. The application is doing that when I interact with the first element (login page). After filling the login field spec then stops with the message "(uncaught exception) TypeError: Fullscreen request denied".

Is there any way to  work around this? On higher resolutions where full screen is not opened spec passes without problem.

[Screen with the error from Cypress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUBHg.png)

I was searching if there is a parameter in Cypress settings to disable the blocker for full screen , unfortunately I did not find anything.
The same problem occurs on Chrome and Firefox.

The spec code is very simple

I use the class from POM

```js
class Homepage_PO {
Visit_Homepage(){
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('integrax_homepage'),{timeout:60000})
}
Login(login, password){
    cy.get('input[name="login"]').type(login)
    cy.get('input[name="password"]').type(password)
    cy.get('#loginBtn').click()
}

}

export default Homepage_PO;
```

and the spec code

```js
import Homepage_PO from "../../support/pageObjects/integraX/Homepage_PO";

/// <reference types = 'cypress'/>

describe('Log in into IntegraX', () => {
    const homepage_PO = new Homepage_PO()
    
    beforeEach(() => {
        homepage_PO.Visit_Homepage();
    });
    it.only('log in as Integra administrator', () => {
        homepage_PO.Login(Cypress.env('integra_admin_login'), Cypress.env('integra_admin_password'));
    });

    it('log in as Car Service', () => {
        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to disable fullscreen by replacing the method on the element or documentElement.

See [How TO - Fullscreen](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen.asp).

If the call is at element level

```js
const stub = cy.stub();
cy.get('input[name="password"]')
  .then($el => $el[0].requestFullscreen = stub)
  .type(password)
  .then(() => expect(stub).to.be.called)
```

or if the call is at document level

```js
const stub = cy.stub();
cy.document().then(doc => {
  doc.documentElement.requestFullscreen = stub
})
cy.get('input[name="password"]')
  .type(password)
  .then(() => expect(stub).to.be.called)
```

---

In case this method cannot be stubbed, you can catch the uncaught exception error and just let the test carry on

```js
Cypress.once('uncaught:exception', () => 
  return false
})
cy.get('input[name="password"]')
  .type(password)                 // error suppressed by above handler
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

This solution worked in my case (the call is at document level)

```
const stub = cy.stub();
cy.document().then(doc => {
  doc.documentElement.requestFullscreen = stub
})
cy.get('input[name="password"]')
  .type(password)
  .then(() => expect(stub).to.be.called)
```

This solution also werked but I'll need to add it to each field. The same problem occured when I was clicking "Login" btton. So abowe solution is much better.

```
Cypress.once('uncaught:exception', () => 
  return false
})
cy.get('input[name="password"]')
  .type(password)                 // error suppressed by above handler
```